# How to reset loaded classes fast in java?

Tags: java, performance, classloader

I'm using a custom classloader to load some java classes. I need to execute some methods from these loaded classes in a loop. For each loop iteration I need a fresh initialization of all the classes (all static fields). I have measured that the execution time is three times slower if I use a new classloader for each iteration than the execution time when not using a fresh classloader in each iteration.

Can I reset the loaded classes to their initial state without loading them with a new classloader?

Or is there a way to speed up recurring loading of the same classes in different classloaders?

Answer (score 2):

When you load the class with a new classloader, the JMV will almost certainly have to [re-jit the byte code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). Until it does, the first uses of the newly loaded classes will be slower.

I assume these classes are library code which you cannot modify? Because the fact that you're having to use the classes in this way suggests flawed design to me.

Comment: It's a security feature. The classes are uploaded by the user and executed inside the server system.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head: can you take a snapshot of the initial state of the class using reflection and then restoring it?

Comment: What if the fields are final?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection